# Ionic 3 Storage: How to correctly get array of JSON objects?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the following array JSON objects and try to keep them locally using Ionic storage:

```
Country[5]
0: {record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "USA"}
1: {record_id: "2", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Japan"}
2: {record_id: "3", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Korea"}
3: {record_id: "4", local_TimeStamp: "15:00:00", country: "Thailand"}
4: {record_id: "5", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "China"}
```

Code:

```
export class HomePage {
localarray: any = []; 

constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams,
```

private storage: Storage){ }

```
this.storage.set('localrows', JSON.stringify(this.Country));  

// Try to get the whole array JSON object back:
let TIME_IN_MS = 2000;
let someTimeout = setTimeout( () =>
{ 
  this.storage.get('localrows').then( (data) => {
    this.localarray.push(JSON.parse(data))});
  console.dir(this.localarray);
}, TIME_IN_MS);
```

Instead of the expected return Country[5].
I got this result from my console log:

```
Array(0)
0
:
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]  <= The original array JSON Objects stored here !
```

What's wrong with the code so that it'll return Country[5].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I want to suggest you use `localStorage`

For your demand setting value:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('localrows',JSON.stringify(this.Country));
```

And getting value:

```
   this.localarray =JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('localrows'));
```

Hope you will be helpful

Comment: Thanks Utpaul.  I tried but it return: Array(0)
length
:
0

Comment: @LHLK print console.log(this.localarray); inside promise

Comment: I suggest for this purpose localstorage .... I you use storage then you need to make provider to get this data into your variable...

Comment: OK. I'm new to Ionic and I'll try to put it inside the existing http provider...Hey thanks...

Answer (score 1):

See the docs at https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

You have to install and set it up first:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage

npm install --save @ionic/storage
```

Include it in your `app.module.ts` imports:

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

// Inside of your @NgModule
imports: [
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot() // Add this
],
```

Then, on the page you're using it on, reference it like this:

```
public user: any = {};
constructor(private storage: Storage)
```

and you can retrieve arrays like this:

```
storage.get('user').then((userdata) => {
    this.user = userdata;
});
```

and then if you must have it as an array, you can always parse it from JSON `JSON.parse(this.user)`

Hopefully this will assist someone else using Ionic to steer away from `localStorage` and use a native option instead.